# How to find the polynomial with integer (positive and/or negative coefficients) exactly satisfying 4 given points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to find polynomial (of whatever degree) with integer (positive and/or negative coefficients) exactly satisfying 4 given points:

$\{x=6,y=6670\},\{x=2,y=55\},\{x=1,y=10\},\{x=0,y=1\}$

Anyone ?

Answer (score 8):

There are none.  The last point gives the constant term to be $1$.  For the first point, all the powers of $x$ are even, so the value of the whole polynomial will be odd.

Answer (score 2):

The *unique* ([Lagrange interpolating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)) degree-$3$ polynomial passing
*exactly* through the four given points with integer coordinates is
$$
\eqalign{
f(x)&=&
6670\frac{(x-0)(x-1)(x-2)}{(6-0)(6-1)(6-2)}+
  55\frac{(x-0)(x-1)(x-6)}{(2-0)(2-1)(2-6)}\\&&+
  10\frac{(x-0)(x-2)(x-6)}{(1-0)(1-2)(1-6)}+
    \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(x-6)}{(0-1)(0-2)(0-6)}\\&=&
\frac{6670}{6\cdot5\cdot4}x(x-1)(x-2)-
\frac{  55}{2\cdot4}x(x-1)(x-6)\\&&+
\frac{  10}{5}x(x-2)(x-6)-
\frac{   1}{2\cdot6}(x-1)(x-2)(x-6)\\&=&
\frac{405}{8}x^3 - \frac{1071}{8}x^2 + \frac{369}{4}x + 1\\&=&
\frac18\left(405x^3 - 1071x^2 + 738x + 8\right)\,.
}$$
It has **rational**, but in general not ingegral coefficients,
as one expects for data points $(x_i,y_i)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.
Since the it is unique, there is no polynomial of degree $3$ with
integer coefficients that exactly passes through these data points.
One could, however, find the "closest" *approximation* in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$,
given a suitable definition of closeness,
for example with [Bernstein polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial).

Thanks to an astute reader (@YongyiChen)
for pointing out that we can always
search for a *higher degree* polynomial.
And as @RossMillikan already argued,
this is impossible, for if
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$$
were such a polynomial, then we would have $a_0=1$ and
$$
y_k-1 = \sum_{i=1}^na_ix_k^i
$$
for the $k^{\text{th}}$ data point,
which necessarily entails that $x_k|y_k-1$
for each data point with $x_k\ne0$.
However, this is not true for $(6,6670)$
since $6669\equiv3\pmod6$.

Comment: There is more than one polynomial if we don't restrict its degree to one less than the number of given points.

Comment: @YongyiChen: thanks, you're spot on!

Comment: @YongyiChen:  But it still won't work over the integers.

Comment: Any closed form function then ?

Comment: What do you mean? There's a polynomial, just with rational coefficients.

Comment: Not polynomial, I meant

Comment: But with integral coefficients?? @AlekseyPichugin has a nice quadratic form for an ellipse passing through your points.

Comment: Yes, Alexey offered very nice answer, where y could be resolved (as quadratic equation solution) over x - in radicals over integral values - that is great !, how did you arrive to it ?

Answer (score 2):

Are we expected to construct polynomials in $x$ only, or can we consider powers of $y$ as well? Because the following polynomial equation does satisfy all of your points:
$$
36576-322659x+651393x^2-36581y+5y^2=0.
$$
It is an ellipse.

Comment: Which could be solved over radicals with regards to y - that is good !

Comment: Could you maybe explain how you obtained this ellipse?

Comment: @J.M. It is embarassingly simple: I just analytically solved the system of four equations in Maple. The only "know how" here, I suppose, was to assume that the question must make sense somehow and, after seeing Ross Millikan's argument, it was clear that more general form is likely to be assumed.

Comment: Do I need to put more details of the solution?

Comment: Oh, it's an axis-aligned ellipse; I only noticed it now...

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't mind broadening your attention to real coefficients**, check out Lagrange interpolation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial . For $n$ points, there is a polynomial of degree $n$ which interpolates those points, given by the formula on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not force the coefficients to be integers.  For $n$ points, it is the polynomial of degree $n-1$ that is unique.

Comment: Oh, argh, integer coefficients.  Question reading fail.

Comment: Any closed form function then ?